# How are Applications Removed from the IIS Application Pool?

Tags: iis, iis-7

We've got a new server, and I am trying to set it up for our website.

I got a new application for the engineers set up in the **Application Pools** called `eng_app`, then added our applications to it.

Now, we have been given an external drive that these applications need to be on, but I can't seem to edit or delete the existing applications.

I tried following the [Microsoft Technet Article • Remove an Application (IIS 7)](http://technet.microsoft.com/en-us/library/cc771205(v=ws.10).aspx) but, as you can see in the screenshot, those are incorrect.

> C:\Windows\System32\inetsrv>appcmd delete app "eng_app/drawing"
> **ERROR ( message:Cannot find APP object with identifier "eng_app/drawing". )**
>
> C:\Windows\System32\inetsrv>appcmd delete app "/eng_app/drawing"
> **ERROR ( message:Must specify the APP object with identifier or "APP.NAME" parameter. )**

### Could someone tell me what I missed here?

[image: screenshot]

Answer (score 2, accepted):

OK, it looks like you can't do it either through the command line or using the Application Pool interface.

After stopping the webservice, what I did was:

1. go down to the list of Sites and select my application from the list,
2. click **Basic Settings...**
3. change the *Application pool* with the **Select...** button and edit the *Physical path*

Afterwards, you can restart the webservice.

[image: screenshot]

There might be a better way, but this is how I did it.

Answer (score 22):

Using Powershell

0. Go to folder

   `cd C:\Windows\system32\inetsrv`
1. List all applications to get the correct APP.NAME

   `.\appcmd list app`
2. Delete the application using fullname for <APP.NAME>.
   Ex.: "Default Web Site/The.Application".
   I mean, you must put it with web site name including the double-quotes.

   `.\appcmd delete app <APP.NAME>`

Comment: I'll upvote it, but I do not work in software anymore. I cannot test this to confirm if it solved my problem from 5+ years ago.

Comment: This works like a charm. For the last command make sure to add double quotes around the APP.NAME. Thats. it! 
.\appcmd delete app "<APP.NAME>"

Comment: worth noting that you have to enable IIS under 'turn windows features on or off' on your local machine.

Comment: I am baffled as to why there isn't a simple ui to do this. But this command does work, thank you!

Answer (score 0):

`appcmd delete app eng_app/drawing`

Comment: I suppose you can add a brief explanation of your provided solution.

Answer (score 0):

The problem could also be solved with a dummy application pool:

1. Create a new application pool in IIS with name e.g. "ToDeletePool"
2. Change application pool in IIS of applications that you want to delete from your application pool to "ToDeletePool" (right click you application pool, select "view applications" and then "change application pool"):[image]
3. Remove Application pool "ToDeletePool" in cmd

3.a cd %SystemRoot%\System32\inetsrv

3.b Remove-WebAppPool -Name ToDeletePool

Answer (score 0):

my experience solved:
List Applications: You can use the appcmd list app command to obtain a list of all the applications configured on your server, using powershell:

First: Go to the default installation directory for Internet Information Services (IIS):

cd C:\Windows\system32\inetsrv

Second: run command is used to list the web applications configured in IIS:

appcmd list app

Result:
Name App
APP "xxxxxxxxxxxxxxxxxxxxxxxxxxxxxxxx" (applicationPool:xxxxxxxxxxx)

Third: Delete Application: Use the appcmd delete app command to delete a specific application. Adjust the app name as needed.

appcmd delete app /app.name:miservicio.serv.com/site/site1

For example:

appcmd delete app /app.name:miservicio.serv.com/site/site1/site1.1

Delete Apps with a Prefix: You can use wildcards to delete multiple apps with a common prefix.

appcmd delete app /app.name:miservicio.serv.com/site/site1/site1.1/*